# Функция, которая возвращает повторяющиеся слова и буквы

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

> Напишите функцию `stats(s)`, принимающую на вход строку s, содержащую слова, разделённые пробелами или переводами строки, и находящую самое часто встречающееся слово. Если такое слово одно, верните его, если их несколько, верните список, в котором они перечислены все (в любом порядке). Использовать внешние библиотеки нельзя!

Например: `stats("hello hello world")` должна вернуть строчку "hello", а `stats("a a b b c")` должна вернуть список `['a','b']` или `['b','a']`.

Проверка решения:

```
def checkstats(i, o):
    if len(o)>1:
        assert set(stats(i))==set(o)
    else:
        assert stats(i)==o

checkstats("apple orange banana banana orange",['banana', 'orange'])
checkstats("""q w e r t y u i o p
a s d f g h j k l
z x c v b n m""",  
           ['b', 'm', 'p', 'z', 'u', 'j', 't', 'e', 'w', 'g', 's', 'k', 'v', 'f', 'r', 
            'c', 'x', 'a', 'n', 'y', 'l', 'i', 'q', 'h', 'd', 'o'])
checkstats("""vqcg vqcg vqcg vqcg vqcg vqcg vqcg
vqcg vqcg
vqcg
""", 'vqcg')
checkstats("""Death there mirth way the noisy merit. Piqued shy spring nor six though mutual living ask extent. Replying of dashwood advanced ladyship smallest disposal or. Attempt offices own improve now see. Called person are around county talked her esteem. Those fully these way nay thing seems.
At distant inhabit amongst by. Appetite welcomed interest the goodness boy not. Estimable education for disposing pronounce her. John size good gay plan sent old roof own. Inquietude saw understood his friendship frequently yet. Nature his marked ham wished.
Marianne or husbands if at stronger ye. Considered is as middletons uncommonly. Promotion perfectly ye consisted so. His chatty dining for effect ladies active. Equally journey wishing not several behaved chapter she two sir. Deficient procuring favourite extensive you two. Yet diminution she impossible understood age.
So if on advanced addition absolute received replying throwing he. Delighted consisted newspaper of unfeeling as neglected so. Tell size come hard mrs and four fond are. Of in commanded earnestly resources it. At quitting in strictly up wandered of relation answered felicity. Side need at in what dear ever upon if. Same down want joy neat ask pain help she. Alone three stuff use law walls fat asked. Near do that he help.
Betrayed cheerful declared end and. Questions we additions is extremely incommode. Next half add call them eat face. Age lived smile six defer bed their few. Had admitting concluded too behaviour him she. Of death to or to being other.
Consulted he eagerness unfeeling deficient existence of. Calling nothing end fertile for venture way boy. Esteem spirit temper too say adieus who direct esteem. It esteems luckily mr or picture placing drawing no. Apartments frequently or motionless on reasonable projecting expression. Way mrs end gave tall walk fact bed.
Offered say visited elderly and. Waited period are played family man formed. He ye body or made on pain part meet. You one delay nor begin our folly abode. By disposed replying mr me unpacked no. As moonlight of my resolving unwilling.
Folly words widow one downs few age every seven. If miss part by fact he park just shew. Discovered had get considered projection who favourable. Necessary up knowledge it tolerably. Unwilling departure education is be dashwoods or an. Use off agreeable law unwilling sir deficient curiosity instantly. Easy mind life fact with see has bore ten. Parish any chatty can elinor direct for former. Up as meant widow equal an share least.
With my them if up many. Lain week nay she them her she. Extremity so attending objection as engrossed gentleman something. Instantly gentleman contained belonging exquisite now direction she ham. West room at sent if year. Numerous indulged distance old law you. Total state as merit court green decay he. Steepest sex bachelor the may delicate its yourself. As he instantly on discovery concluded to. Open draw far pure miss felt say yet few sigh.
Out too the been like hard off. Improve enquire welcome own beloved matters her. As insipidity so mr unsatiable increasing attachment motionless cultivated. Addition mr husbands unpacked occasion he oh. Is unsatiable if projecting boisterous insensible. It recommend be resolving pretended middleton.""", 'or')
checkstats("enagtgufzhnmyzkf kaphgquvoanw tkvj sylaejugfsv vuszbsdsv kmyyed rnhcdrpx b ejqa vykiu fjmdqlgxmameddhiytv yy owmldhdcjnoi durqhg ftjnehww aq ou tqxlcnxdpnmo ssdhbcdzzp twjdcvcojgtj", ['b', 'yy', 'twjdcvcojgtj', 'tqxlcnxdpnmo', 'ou', 'durqhg', 'fjmdqlgxmameddhiytv', 'ssdhbcdzzp', 'sylaejugfsv', 'kaphgquvoanw', 'rnhcdrpx', 'owmldhdcjnoi', 'ejqa', 'tkvj', 'enagtgufzhnmyzkf', 'aq', 'vuszbsdsv', 'kmyyed', 'ftjnehww', 'vykiu'])
```

Я не смог вывести строкой слово, если оно повторяется только раз. Более того, написал очень громоздкий код:

```
def stats(*s):

    l = []
    x = {}
    for i in s:
        if type(i) is tuple:
            y = [i for i in s for i in i]
            for i in y:
                if type(i) is str:
                    x = {i for i in i.split()}

                elif type(i) is list:
                    x = {i for i in i}

        elif type(i) is str:
            x = {i for i in i.split()}

            y = [i for i in i.split()]

        elif type(i) is list:
            x = {i for i in i}

    for i in x:
        y.count(i)
        if y.count(i) > 1 and len(i) > 1:
            if y.count((y.count(i) > 1)) == 1:
                i = str(i)

            else:
                l.append(i)
        elif y.count(i) > 1 and len(i) == 1:

            l.append(i)

    return l
```

Как можно решить более эффективно?

Comment: @CrazyElf Добрый день! Посмотрите пожалуйста, если есть возможность.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант решения "в лоб" - делаем все за один проход:

```
def stats(string_):
    freq = {}
    res = []
    for word in string_.split():
        freq[word] = freq[word] + 1 if word in freq else 1
        if freq[word] > 1 and word not in res:
            res.append(word)
    if len(res) == 0:
        return None
    return res if len(res) > 1 else res.pop()
```

---

тесты:

```
In [2]: stats("hello hello world")
Out[2]: 'hello'

In [3]: stats("a a b b c")
Out[3]: ['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Можно без `replace("\n", " ")` - `split()` и без замены нормально разделит.

Comment: Благодарю, решение компактнее, только работает на примерах '''stats("hello hello world")''' и '''stats("a a b b c")'''. На других выводит ошибку.

Comment: @insolor, не смог найти этой "фичи" в документации, но на практике, похоже, работает

Comment: @SultanTapi, а на каких строках не проходит тесты? PS я менял код в ответе - вы использовали последнюю версию ответа?

Comment: например, вот с этими аргументами не работает: ("apple orange banana banana orange",['banana', 'orange'])

Comment: @SultanTapi, у меня `checkstats("apple orange banana banana orange",['banana', 'orange'])` - отрабатывет правильно...

Comment: @MaxU, по поводу этой фичи, см. [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), после первого примера кода со слов "If sep is not specified or is `None`..."

Comment: @MaxU прикольно получается. '''checkstats("apple orange banana banana orange",['banana', 'orange'])''' - реально отрабатывает. НО, если я те же аргументы использую без функции "checkstats" - выдает ошибку. Другой момент - "checkstats" с другими аргументами к сожалению не работает.=(

Comment: @MaxU Пишет, что даны 2 аргумента, а когда добавляю *, то выводит ''''tuple' object has no attribute 'split''''.

Comment: @SultanTapi, в задании требовалось написать `"функцию, принимающую на вход строку s`" - о втором аогументе или о кортеже речи не было. Вы определитесь пожалуйста какую функцию вы хотите создать и что она должна принимать в качестве параметров - единственную строку, две строки, кортеж или что-то еще.

Comment: @MaxU слушайте, я просто хочу понять, как решить задачу. Если бы я знал все тонкости, я бы не обращался за помощью.

Comment: @SultanTapi, ну мы здесь как бы и пытаемся вам в этом помочь ;)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это решение и конечно, если у вас есть тестирующая система, замените сообщение об ошибке на нужный результат в случае получения на вход пустой строки.

```
def stats(words):
    freq = dict()
    words = words.split()

    for word in words:
        freq[word] = freq[word] + 1 if word in freq else 1

    words = sorted(list(set(words)), key = lambda w: freq[w])

    r = []
    i = len(words)-1

    if not len(words):
        return "[Error] No words found"
    while freq[words[i]] == freq[words[-1]]:
        r.append(words[i])
        if not i:
            return r if len(r) > 1 else r[0]
        i -= 1


    return r if len(r) > 1 else r[0]

# Testing:
print(stats("a a a a a b b g g g g t t t o"))        # a
print(stats("a a a a a b b b b b g g g g t t t o"))  # ['a', 'b']
print(stats("a a a a a b b g g g g g t t t o"))      # ['a', 'g']
print(stats("a b c d"))                              # ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']
print(stats("a a a a"))                              # a
print(stats("a"))                                    # a
print(stats(""))                                     # [Error] No words found
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. С аргументами '''("apple orange banana banana orange",['banana', 'orange'])''' не работает. Пишет, что даны 2 аргумента, а когда добавляю *, то выводит ''''tuple' object has no attribute 'split''''.

Comment: Это значит, что функция `stats` принимает на вход объект типа **tuple** (кортеж) и в строке `words.split()` пытается его разделить по пробелу. К объекту tuple нельзя применить метод `split()`, о чем и пишет ошибка. Предположу, что вы вызываете функцию `checkstats()`, передавая ей на вход кортеж, как один аргумент. Когда же она сообщает, что ей нужно больше (2 аргумента), вы передаете ей один, передавая кортеж, а не строку, функции `stats`.

Comment: Используйте функцию `checkstats` следующим образом
`checkstats("apple orange banana banana orange",['banana', 'orange'])`

Comment: благодарю за разъяснение!

Comment: Если мой ответ вам помог, поставьте, пожалуйста, стрелочку вверх и галочку. Это поможет мне :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def stats(st="a a b b c d e b a d"):
    ls = st.split()
    dc = {w: ls.count(w) for w in set(ls)}
    m = max(dc.values())
    return [k for k in dc if dc[k] == m]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, только с аргументами '''("apple orange banana banana orange",['banana', 'orange'])''' не работает, выдает ошибку. Пишет, что даны 2 аргумента, а когда добавляю *, то выводит ''''tuple' object has no attribute 'split''''.

Comment: тогда потрудитесь изучить основы питона, прежде чем приступать к решению задач

Comment: Вадим, к сожалению, ваше решение не является верным даже при условии правильного подхода к тестированию, поскольку всегда возвращает список.

Comment: @vadimvaduxa гениально. Знал бы, что такие подсказки даёте, сразу к вам обратился бы.